# How can I reload code in a Clojure pedestal repl for a quick development workflow?

Tags: clojure, pedestal

I am using Pedestal (pedestal.io) and in development am running the server from inside a repl.

When I make a change to the application code (such as changing the html template) how can I have the repl reflect these changes automatically upon save of file and have them show up on browser refresh?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to refer to the [`auto-reload-server`](https://github.com/pedestal/samples/tree/master/auto-reload-server) sample which uses [`ns-tracker` for watching changes](https://github.com/pedestal/samples/blob/master/auto-reload-server/dev/dev.clj#L38) in your code.